# How to create WMS service with GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I am trying to build first WMS service with GeoServer. I have made layer from shape and layer preview works fine. How can I open this layer with QGIS? How to do map with OpenLayers?

I have tried to search GeoServer/OpenLayers guide for Dummies, but not find yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do GIS web apps work?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21452/how-do-gis-web-apps-work)

Comment: @iant It definitely isn't an exact duplicate of that question. That question dealt with WebMapping, and looking at the question, I feel that OP might be asking about WMS clients in general( Given that Qgis is present in the question)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to work with QGIS at first. Of course I would like to use it in other programs also. When connecting, should I add http://server:8080/ or http://server:8080/geoserver/ or what? What I have to do at server after creating layer with GeoServer?

Comment: Now I managed to get it work! I add http://server:8080/geoserver/Workspace/

Comment: my answer to that question (atleast) discussed how to use WMS in OL and other clients

Answer (score 2):

Geoserver can server WMS requests. You need a WMS client to take advantage of this, and see the data. OpenLayers is a browser based WMS clients. There are thousands (millions ?) of WMS clients, and Qgis is just one of them.

To consume a WMS service in Qgis, you need to go to Layer >> Add WMS Layer in Qgis' Menu.

This is an excellent tutorial on consuming WMS services in Qgis: 
[Tutorial: Using Online Data via WMS in Quantum GIS](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/05/tutorial-using-online-data-via-wms-in.html)

Comment: Ok, problem 1 solved, but how to make map from same GeoServer layer with OpenLayers?

Comment: @GISSami Have you looked at: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wms.html

Comment: I have tried similar to that, but both give error **code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers"could not find layer basic**

Comment: Now I got it! Just replacing _basic_ with my layer! Thanks for help!

Comment: Not sure if this is best way to do this `var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://server:8080/geoserver/ows/", {layers: 'Rakennusviivat,Hallintoalue,Kiinteistoraja'} );
        var dm_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Rakennukset",
            "http://server:8080/geoserver/ows/",
            {
                layers: "Rakennusviivat,Hallintoalue,Kiinteistoraja",
                transparent: "true",
                format: "image/png"
            },
            {isBaseLayer: false}
        );`