# GeoServer create map from image

Tags: geoserver, cartography, openlayers-2, image

Can i create a map using plain image(jpg or png) with GeoServer and OpenLayers?

Scenario as i see it:

- I upload image(somehow) to GeoServer and it converts it to a map layer
- Then i create a simple html file with OpenLayers connected, and grab my layer from GeoServer

Any tutorials or documentation? I tried to find solution for this case by myself, but unsuccessfully.

Or may be i misunderstand something general in GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.

- Geo-reference the image first, this can be done with the [QGIS
  geo-referenceing tool](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html), you will need some background mapping for
  reference.
- Publish the image with a WMS through [GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57139/how-to-create-wms-service-with-geoserver). Just install
  geoserver locally and create a datastore on a local drive.
- Create a simple webmap  with [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wms.html) and view WMS
  from GeoServer.

It might be worth looking at [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/).

Comment: Thank you @Matt! I figured it out. Buе I found how to georeference my image as GeoTIFF. How can I convert it to .jgw or .pgw?

Comment: Take a look at using GDAL translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html via the OSGeo Shell or GDAL command line tool.

Comment: You can also use a GeoTiff image directly with GeoServer (or a directory of GeoTiffs with the Image Mosaic plugin).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll try GDAL. And I have already deployed my map via GeoTiff to GeoServer, thank to you:-) As well, may be you know the right way to create georeferenced image from .jpg or .png from Java? Or it will be easier to build my own .jgw or .pwg for concrete image?