# Georeference map from videogame

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geoserver

I am trying to georeference a map from a Videogame to display it on a website, probably with openlayers.

The map in question is this [Subnautica map](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/File:Subnautica_map2.png).

I found a starting point here [GeoServer create map from image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152400/112982). I managed to Reference the map in Qgis with some coordinates and export the layer to GeoServer and display it there.
My Problem is that I don't know how to proceed from there. I'd like to map the map 1:1 to "real world" coordinates, so that the center of this map is at 0,0 on the website. I think I have to chose a Map projection, like Web Mercator, and calculate where the coordinates from the game would be in the real world?

The map in the game is 4kmx4km in size.

Comment: How big is the image file?

Will you be creating extra data? It's likely that you can make the map using GeoJSON and then you don't need GeoServer. Also, look into Leaflet. Note that with Leaflet, you can place a regular image on the map (even using arbitrary coordinates).

Comment: The image is about 4mb right now, but maybe later i will add some aerial images. You guessed right, I want to add some additional info later, like Point of interest and such. Seems like I can use  gdal2tiles to split an image and feed that into leaflet. But ho do I reference the image like I described?

Comment: 4 MB is still pretty small. Tiling it is a lot more complex! I'll add an answer with what I think you could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the image from the web site, chopped out the legend etc, and ended up with an image that was 2883x288 pixels. If this is 4km x 4km then each pixel is 1.387 metres.

To geolocate this image at (0,0) ("Null Island") create a "world file" using a text editor with this:

```
1.387444
0
0
-1.387444
0
0
```

and save this as `Subnautica_map2.pngw` - that is, the name of the image but with extension `pngw`.

Load this into QGIS and tell QGIS it is in EPSG:3857 and it should appear off the coast of Africa.

Here it is with a QGIS measurer showing the 4km size of the edge.

[image]

Note that the size of a unit in EPSG:3857 is only one metre at the equator, so if you try and load it further north or south it won't be a nice round 4km.

Comment: Very nice and neat solution! Now that the file has a World file to georeference it, it'll be possible to turn it into x/y/z tiles that you can use in a webserver and load into Leaflet that way.

Comment: WOW... I took this approach but used "aerial images" from the game and fed them into gdal2tiles. It even had a sample html page with the map.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your image into a real world coordinate system, I think you should use QGIS to georeference it using a 'world file' and the coordinate system '3857' (which is what Leaflet uses). Pick somewhere in the middle of the map, or maybe even around  'null island' (so lon/lat of 0/0).

Now you can load your image in QGIS, which means you can start digitising features and saving them as GeoJSON (which you can [add to a Leaflet map](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson)). And you can add your [image to Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#imageoverlay) too. And all of this will be in the same mythical coordinate system!

Later, if you need to, you can look at tiled Vector and Raster data.

(Ultimately, if you have a complex map, you could make it all vector tiles and use MapBoxGL for a really nice map! Leaflet is a good simple way to get started, though.)

Comment: You  can write the world file by hand using a text editor once you know the image dimension (pixels x pixels) and the size of the image on the map (which you say is 4km x 4km). Everything is N-S/E-W aligned which makes the world file trivial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file